# How do I add JQuery mobile styles to a table row that is created on the fly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have some code in my JQuery UI/Coldfusion application that allows the user to add a row to a table and delete rows where required.
The first row is not created dynamically so the JQuery Mobile styling is applied to this row.
How do I add the same styling to the dynamically created additional rows that the user may add?

My code is this:

javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;

$("#addrow").on("click", function () {

    counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><select name="urltype' + counter + '" id="urltype' + counter + '" data-native-menu="false"><option>Select a URL type</option><cfoutput query="variables.qryurltype"><option value="#NC_VALUE_ID#">#TC_MED_DESC#</option></cfoutput></select></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" name="url' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});

$("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();


    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
});

});


});//]]>  

</script>
```

and my html is:

```
  <table id="myTable" class="order-list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>URL Type</td>
        <td>URL</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="select_url_type" id="select_url_type" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Select a URL type</option>
             <cfoutput query="variables.qryurltype">
                <option value="#NC_VALUE_ID#">#TC_MED_DESC#</option>
             </cfoutput>
            </select>   
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="url" />
        </td>
        <td><a class="deleteRow"></a><input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Row" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right;">

        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I am using the following JQuery components:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
 <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

regards

JC

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You do not have any styles specified in your table. The added rows should just pick up the styles of the parent container. As an example I created a jsFiddle from the code that you provided and it works fine. [See the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HE6GY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call enhanceWithin() on the table after adding the rows:

```
$("table.order-list").append(newRow).enhanceWithin();
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kkLrw/)**

This assumes you are not using the jQM table widget, but just a plain table with jQM widgets in the table cells.